# Unable to set VM startup script metadata via Google Cloud Workflows

Tags: google-workflows

I'm trying to use Cloud Workflows to modify the metadata of an existing VM. Basically, the VM has some expensive proprietary software on it, and I'm wanting to run it headless via a workflow whenever new data comes in. Licensing restrictions mean I can't use images/templates etc. I have a function that creates the script and uploads to a bucket, so I just need to set the metadata before I start the VM via the workflow.

Example:

startupscript.sh (living in gs://(bucket)/startupscript.sh):
`echo "hello world from startup script" > helloworld.txt && gsutil cp helloworld.txt gs://<bucket>`

Create demo VM:
`gcloud compute instances create workflow-metadata-setting-test --project=*** --zone=us-central1-c --machine-type=e2-micro --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write`

workflow.yaml:

```
get_vm_fingerprint:
  params: [project, zone, instance]
  steps:
    - get_instance:
        call: googleapis.compute.v1.instances.get
        args:
          instance: ${instance}
          project: ${project}
          zone: ${zone}
        result: instance
    - extract_result:
        return: ${instance.metadata.fingerprint}

main:
  params: [event]
  steps:
    - init:
        assign:
          - project: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
          - zone: us-central1-c
          - instance: "workflow-metadata-setting-test"

    - getFingerprint:
        call: get_vm_fingerprint
        args:
          instance: ${instance}
          project: ${project}
          zone: ${zone}
        result: fingerprint

    - setMetadata:
        call: googleapis.compute.beta.instances.setMetadata
        args:
            instance: ${instance}
            project: ${project}
            zone: ${zone}
            body:
                fingerprint: ${fingerprint}
                items:
                    key: startup-script-url
                    value: gs://<bucket>/startupscript.sh
        result: setMetadataResult

    - start_machine:
        call: googleapis.compute.v1.instances.start
        args:
          instance: ${instance}
          project: ${project}
          zone: ${zone}

    - return_result:
        return: ${setMetadataResult}
```

In theory, there should be a file called "helloworld.txt" living in gs://(bucket) after running this workflow, however, there is not. If you got into the VM details via the console, the metadata is shown as "None"

However, I do get a successful completion message displayed from setMetadataResult (I've added *** and ... for anonymity reasons):

```
{
  "endTime": "2023-08-09T21:17:28.983-07:00",
  "id": "7738306016998709***",
  "insertTime": "2023-08-09T21:17:28.535-07:00",
  "kind": "compute#operation",
  "name": "operation-1691641047461-60289dfb8ad83-297311a8-8a14****",
  "operationType": "setMetadata",
  "progress": 100,
  "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/.../operations/operation-1691641047461-60289dfb8ad83-297311a8-8a14****",
  "startTime": "2023-08-09T21:17:28.641-07:00",
  "status": "DONE",
  "targetId": "860253131759589****",
  "targetLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/.../instances/workflow-test",
  "user": "****15104615-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "zone": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/..."
}
```

Does this work for anyone else? I don't know if its a permissions thing
(if it were, I'd be expecting a different response to what I get), or a bug.
I can set the startup-script-url metadata via console and via gcloud CLI, but just not via workflow...

Cheers!

Comment: Can you check with this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/access-control).  Are you getting any error messages?  if so, can you share it?

Comment: Hi Sandeep,
Thanks for responding.

I'm not sure its a permissions issue.
I can add/modify/execute the workflow no problems, and I have permissions to modify the VM (eg I can do it via the Gcloud SDK). The service account that is running the workflow (ie the "user" in the above completion message) has compute.instances.setMetadata granted also.
I would have thought that the status in the completion message would be "failed" if the wrong permissions were in place, as it is it says "DONE", which makes me think that GCP thinks it has completed the task successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, I noticed on https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setMetadata that items should be a list, not a dict. It started working by simply adding a '-' and appropriate indenting:

```
    - setMetadata:
        call: googleapis.compute.beta.instances.setMetadata
        args:
            instance: ${instance}
            project: ${project}
            zone: ${zone}
            body:
                fingerprint: ${fingerprint}
                items:
                    - key: startup-script-url
                      value: gs://<bucket>/startupscript.sh
        result: setMetadataResult
```